# How do we model algorithms problems with math equations?

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, math

Mathematics has always been a prime tool for making abstract problems into tangible ones thus making their solution easier.
let's take this problem from LeetCode:

**Given a string s, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.**

> Example 1:
>
> Input: s = "abcabcbb" Output: 3 Explanation: The answer is "abc", with
> the length of 3.

> Example 2:
>
> Input: s = "bbbbb" Output: 1 Explanation: The answer is "b", with the
> length of 1.

Is there a method to model this kind of problem or any problem with mathematic equations?

Comment: Your assumption that expressing the problem in a formal mathematical notation would make the problem easier, clearer, or more exact seems unjustified. But give it a try and see what you end up with. A "string" can be view as a sequence of integers between 0 and 2\*\*32, and so forth. I think you'll find it doesn't improve things at all.

Comment: I suggest you change the title to something specific to the problem.

Comment: There is no simple answer to "how do I write code that solves a problem". There's a bunch of techniques, and abstracting the problem into mathematical equations is perhaps one (although a rare one, since changing the language of the problem does not usually make the problem any easier or harder although it may give a new perspective to help with thinking). Mostly algorithms problems are about finding an efficient way of computing the result when a naive approach is too slow (for example here, brute-force checking all substrings), and this isn't usually standard mathematical thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that is linear in computing time (O(n)).

For convenience I have assumed that the letters are all lower case.

Suppose the string is as follows.

```
str = 'abacbdcb'
```

---

Begin by creating a hash whose keys are the lowercase letters of the alphabet and whose value for key 'k' is the index of the string at which the letter 'k' was last "seen" in the string (to be defined). Initially all values are `nil`, meaning no characters have been seen.

```
idx_last_seen = {"a"=>nil, "b"=>nil, "c"=>nil,..., "z"=>nil}
```

---

Create an array `longest` containing one element whose value is `1`:

```
longest = [1]
```

`longest[i]` will be the length of the longest non-repeating string that ends at index `i`.

**Index i = 0**

Initialize the string index and update `idx_last_seen`:

```
i = 0
idx_last_seen[str[i]] = i
```

so now

```
idx_last_seen #=> {"a"=>0, "b"=>nil, "c"=>nil,..., "z"=>nil}
```

**Index i = 1**

Increment the string index and record the character in the string at that index:

```
i += 1 #=> 1
c = str[i] #=> 'b'
```

We wish to now compute `longest[i]`.

```
idx_last_seen[c] = idx_last_seen['b'] #=> nil
```

As `idx_last_seen` has no key `c`, `c` has not been seen before. Therefore, we append `longest` with the last element of `longest` plus `1`.

```
longest << (longest[-1] + 1)
  #=> [1, 2]
```

Here `longest[-1]` denotes the last element of `longest`.

This tells us that the length of the longest non-repeating string ending at index `0` is `1` and the longest non-repeating string ending at index `1` is `2`.

Update `idx_last_seen`:

```
idx_last_seen[str[i]] = i
idx_last_seen
  #=> {"a"=>0, "b"=>1, "c"=>nil,..., "z"=>nil}
```

**Index i = 2**

```
i += 1 #=> 2
c = str[i] #=> 'a'
j = idx_last_seen[c] = idx_last_seen['a'] #=> 0
```

`j = 0` means that `'a'` was last seen at index `0`. Therefore the longest string ending at index `2` equals

```
i - j #=> 2
```

so we append `2` to `longest` and update `idx_last_seen`:

```
longest << i - j
  #=> [1, 2, 2]
idx_last_seen[c] = i
idx_last_seen #=> {"a"=>2, "b"=>1, "c"=>nil,..., "z"=>nil}
```

**Index i = 3**

```
i += 1 #=> 3
c = str[i] #=> 'c'
idx_last_seen[c] = idx_last_seen['c'] #=> nil
```

so `c` has not been seen before. Therefore:

```
longest << (longest[-1] + 1)
  #=> [1, 2, 2, 3]
```

Update `idx_last_seen`

```
idx_last_seen[c] = i
idx_last_seen #=> {"a"=>2, "b"=>1, "c"=>3, "d"=>nil,..., "z"=>nil}
```

**Wrapping up**

Continuing in this way we obtain the following results.

```
 01234567 
'abacbdcb'  longest
 1           'a'
  2          'ab'
   2         'ba'
    3        'bac'
     3       'acb'
      4      'acbd'
       3     'bdc'
        3    'dcb'
         3   'dab'
          2  'ba'
           3 'bac'
```

Each number on the diagonal equals the the length of the maximum non-repeating string that ends at the character of the string that is in the same column above; that is, they are the elements of `longest`. I've already shown the calculations for the first four indices. The string shown to the right of the each number on the diagonal is the associated longest non-repeating string ending at the associated index.

We see that the longest non-repeating string ends at the index `i` for which `longest[i]` is maximum, here `4`, the string `'acbc'`.